# TcpClient: The operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets.

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

```
public Server()
    {
        this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8000);
        this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
        this.listenThread.Start();
    }

    private void ListenForClients()
    {
        this.tcpListener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientCommunication));
            clientThread.Start(tcpClient);
        }
    }

    private void HandleClientCommunication(object client)
    {

        if (client != null)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
            clientList.Add(tcpClient);
        }


        foreach (TcpClient tc in clientList)
        {
            if (tc.Available > 0)
            {
                int dataSize = tc.Available;
                Console.WriteLine("Received data from: " + tc.Client.Handle);

                string text = GetNetworkString(tc.GetStream());

                //transmit
                foreach (TcpClient otherClient in clientList)
                {
                    if (tc.Client.Handle != otherClient.Client.Handle)
                    {
                        // The problem is here:
                        Send(otherClient.GetStream(), text);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }


    private void Send(NetworkStream ns, string data)
    {
        try
        {
                byte[] Bdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                ns.Write(Bdata, 0, Bdata.Length);
                ns.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

I am getting "The operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets." error after the server receives 3-4 messages from the TcpClient. The client, once it is connected to the server, stays online whether the server is down or not. If the server is alive, it can receive the message from the server. If the server is down, the client does not throw any exception but waits until the server become up.

Comment: "the client does not throw any exception but waits until the server become up" - do you mean that it retries connecting until the server comes back up? Otherwise, this is probably a problem (maybe not the one your looking at now). A TCP connection needs to be recreated when one of the parties goes down.